Не могу найти main.py
По какой-то причине при создании нового проекта в пайчарме файл main.py не создается. Создаются лишь файлы .gitignore да pyvenv и папки .idea, Lib и Scripts. С чем это может быть связано и как можно устранить эту проблему?
в ютубе говорили что он автоматически зайдет в main.py но там его нет!!
Что мне делать чтоб найти main.py

Возможно вы создали пустой проект. Если при создании проекта не поставить галочку "Create welcome script", то проект будет пустым: https://i.sstatic.net/b02m5lUr.png. Но никто не мешает создать вам main.py самостоятельно.

Спасибо большое

Возможные причины:

Другой шаблон проекта
При создании проекта выключена опция создания main.py`
Старая версия PyCharm

Но, надеюсь Вы знаете, что можете самостоятельно создать main.py.

Спасибо большое

Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос? => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers
